# I know by Fubinis theorem that $N$ is $\mathcal E$-measurable and $\mu(N)=0$. How can I see that $N \neq X$, that is $N \subset X$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $(X, \mathcal E, \mu)$ and $(Y, \mathcal F, \nu)$ be $\sigma$-finite measure-spaces and consider the product-space $(X \times Y, \mathcal E \oplus \mathcal F, \mu \oplus\nu)$. Let $f: X \times Y \rightarrow \mathbb R$ be a function in $\mathcal L^1(\mu \oplus\nu)$.

Define $N := \{ x \in X : f(x, \cdot) \notin \mathcal L^1(\nu)\} = \{ x \in X : \int_Y \lvert  f(x,y)\rvert \ \nu(dy) = \infty\}$.

I know by Fubinis theorem that $N$ is $\mathcal E$-measurable and $\mu(N)=0$.

How can I see that $N \neq X$, that is $N \subset X$ ?

In case $N = X$, Fubinis theorem does not hold, since I may not integrate over an empty-set in $\mathcal E$.

Comment: If $N=X$ then $\mu(X)=0$ hence $\mu=0$. If $\mu=0$, then every $f$ is integrable for $\mu\otimes\nu=0$ hence $N$ may be any subset of $X$. You probably want to exclude this degenerate case.

Comment: Thanks Did, I guess it is implicit that we only integrate over $N^C$ in case $N \neq X$ then.